# insert div after nth child in bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I've been searching for hours, but just can't figure this out... 
I have a Bootstrap grid and need to inject a div on click after the row where the clicked div is. So, for example, I have 50 lines like

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_1</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_2</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_3</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_4</div>
.
.
.
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_50</div>
```

Now, on a large screen, that's 6 columns per row. If I click on the 3rd div, I need to inject a new div after the 6th. If I click on the 15th div, a new div should be injected after the 18th.
I've tried using `div:nth-child(6n)` but it only works for first row, not the rest.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the logic as shown.

```
  $('div.col-xs-6').on('click', function() {
    var divNo = $('div.col-xs-6').index(this) + 1;
    var insertAfterindex = parseInt((divNo / 6) + 1) * 6;
    if ($('div.col-xs-6').eq(insertAfterindex - 1).length > 0)
      $('div.col-xs-6').eq(insertAfterindex - 1).after('<div>Test</div>');
    else
      $('div.col-xs-6').last().after('<div>Test</div>');
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.col-xs-6').on('click', function() {
    var divNo = $('div.col-xs-6').index(this) + 1;
    var insertAfterindex = parseInt((divNo / 6) + 1) * 6;
    if ($('div.col-xs-6').eq(insertAfterindex - 1).length > 0)
      $('div.col-xs-6').eq(insertAfterindex - 1).after('<div>Test</div>');
    else
      $('div.col-xs-6').last().after('<div>Test</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_1</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_2</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_3</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_4</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_5</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_6</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_7</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_8</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_9</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_10</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_11</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_12</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_13</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_14</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_15</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_16</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_17</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_18</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_19</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">contents_20</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was ALMOST perfect. I made a few changes because the insertAfterindex line was incorrect - try clicking #6 and you'll see it inserts after 12, #12 inserts after 18 etc. But, it did guide me the right way and solved my question so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.col-xs-6.col-sm-6.col-md-3.col-lg-2').on('click', function() {
  $('<div />').insertBefore($(this).next().next().next().next());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col_div">contents_1</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col_div">contents_2</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col_div">contents_3</div>
.
.
.
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col_div">contents_50</div>
```

Try this jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on('click','.col_div',function(e) {
        var div_num = ($( this ).prevAll().length) + 1; // get clicked div's number
        var count = 6 - (div_num % 6);

        var last_div_num_in_row = div_num + count; // get the number of the last div in the row

        var new_div = '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col_div">new div</div>';

        $(".col_div:nth-child("+last_div_num_in_row+")").after(new_div);
    });
});
```